# AWS S3 Loading many files

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, async.js

I need to upload a lot of files (about 65.000) splitted in subdirectory.

I tried to iterate and load every single file like this:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const async = require("async");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const readdir = require("recursive-readdir");
const slash = require("slash");

const { BUCKET, KEY, SECRET } = process.env;
const rootFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, "./");
const uploadFolder = "./test_files/15";
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  signatureVersion: "v4",
  accessKeyId: KEY,
  secretAccessKey: SECRET,
});

function getFiles(dirPath) {
  return fs.existsSync(dirPath) ? readdir(dirPath) : [];
}

async function deploy(upload) {
  if (!BUCKET || !KEY || !SECRET) {
    throw new Error("you must provide env. variables: [BUCKET, KEY, SECRET]");
  }

  const filesToUpload = await getFiles(path.resolve(__dirname, upload));

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    async.eachOfLimit(
      filesToUpload,
      10,
      async.asyncify(async (file) => {
        const Key = file.replace(rootFolder + path.sep, "");
        console.log(`uploading: [${slash(Key)}]`);
        var options = { partSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 4 };
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
          s3.upload(
            {
              Key: slash(Key),
              Bucket: BUCKET,
              Body: fs.readFileSync(file),
            },
            (err) => {
              if (err) {
                return rej(new Error(err));
              }
              res({ result: true });
            }
          );
        });
      }),
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(new Error(err));
        }
        resolve({ result: true });
      }
    );
  });
}

deploy(uploadFolder)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("task complete");
    process.exit(0);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

but after a considerable number of uploads i have this:

```
Error: Error: NetworkingError: connect ETIMEDOUT IP_S3_AWS
```

I need to upload this set of files from ec2 instance (because its a result of a image processing). I have this behavior from my pc, i don't know if from ec2 have the same problem.
I have considered the way of zip all and upload but i need to keep the original directory structure.

I accept also new way to resolve the problem.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: My guess is 65,000 is a bit too much. What size files are they?

Comment: files avarage of 4 KB

Comment: That's way below the max upload size for s3 so shouldn't be that. When you say iterating, are you sending 65,000 individual POST requests?

Comment: Yes, i iterate on my directory and upload every single file.

Comment: It's more than likely that's too many in one go, there's a limit to how many requests you can make within a given time period else you'll get a `429: too many requests` error. Do you only get the error you posted above and not a `429`?

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be much simpler to use the [AWS CLI `aws s3 sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command instead of building this yourself.